# How many languages can you use simultaneously in ONE functioning program in under 500 bytes

Tags: popularity-contest

## Intro

In `Objective-C` (a superset of `C` and an object-oriented language), I can create an object called a `UIWebView`. There is a method for this object called `loadHTMLString:` in which I can load actual `HTML` into the `UIWebView` object itself. I can also inject Javascript into it using the method `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`.

If I were to write a program that created a UIWebView, loaded in my string (which happens to be HTML "code") and then injected a second string (which is Javascript code) I would be using 3 languages at once, in a functional program. (Not sure that `html` is really a programming language... so that's debatable haha)

You can also do things like embed `Python` into `C` (and other languages): https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html

---

This isn't too difficult, with any language you can use other languages inside it if you try hard enough.

---

## Challenge

The challenge here is to see how many languages you can cram into 1 functioning program in under 500 bytes. https://mothereff.in/byte-counter

The program can do literally any task, it just has to work. The languages all have to work together, so you can't have 2 languages running one task, and 3 other languages running a completely different task. So whatever your "task" may be (you decide), there should only be 1 task, and all `n` languages should work on just that 1 task in your 1 program.

---

## Objective

Your score is the number of languages you used. Whoever uses the most languages at once gets a cookie.

Since this is a popularity contest I will be accepting the answer with the most up-votes.

---

## Q&A

•Ray **asked**, "Just to clarify, you're looking for a program that uses multiple languages to accomplish different parts of a single task, as opposed to a polyglot that is a valid program in multiple languages?"
***Answer**, "Yes".*

•DanielM. **asked**, "does Regex count?" ***Answer**, "Yes, I personally WOULD count it. Again, this is a popularity contest, so it really is up to the voters to determine. HTML is not considered a programming language by some, but it has been successfully used in an answer already that has seen quite a few upvotes. (Also, Stack-overflow does define Regex as a programming language if that helps you make your decision to use it or not: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info)*

Comment: Just checking: I'm guessing 0 bytes isn't a valid answer? (Task: Does nothing)

Comment: I think the goal is to use a language, inside another language, etc.

Comment: Correct SuperJedi, this is not a contest for shortest task, this is a contest for most languages nested inside each other, all working to preform a single task (in under 500 bytes)

Comment: Can the task be "do nothing"? If we're trying to cram as many in as possible, it seems like any work or output would detract from the "purity" of that goal ;)

Comment: @Geobits Hahaha, I suppose that will be up to the voters, I have no problem with it ;) As long as your program doesn't crash I'll be selecting the answer with the most languages used. (Or highest score)

Comment: If you're accepting the answer with the most languages used, this is no longer a popularity contest since the winner is not determined by votes.

Comment: @AlexA. In the case I will not be selecting an answer, thank you for pointing that out, I'll add it into my post.

Comment: The point of a popularity contest is that the answer with the most votes gets accepted. Challenges here need an objective winning criterion to be on topic.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're looking for a program that uses multiple languages to accomplish different parts of a single task, as opposed to a polyglot that is a valid program in multiple languages?

Comment: @Ray Exactly!!!

Comment: @AlexA. Edited it in, thank you!

Comment: How would a Sacred {lang} do here? [Sacred](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Sacred). Can I just have a Sacred ... Sacred?

Comment: I've got a cool answer in the works, but I may have a hard time getting it down to 500 bytes...

Comment: Does regex count?

Comment: @DanielM. According to S/O Regex is a type of programming language. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info — I would personally count it, but again, it will most likely be up to the voters to decide ;) Regex def. qualifies more than HTML and HTML has already been successfully used and counted in an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## make, sh, awk, sed, regex, yacc, lex, C; 8 languages.

### Including the input and output languages: brainfuck and D; 10 languages

This is a brainfuck to D compiler.  It takes the brainfuck program over standard input and prints the D code to standard output.

Make uses awk, sed, and sh to generate a yacc program, which in conjunction
with a lex program is used to generate a C program that takes a brainfuck
program as input and outputs an equivalent D program.  I tried to only use languages in ways that were actually useful, instead of just throwing in a bunch of no-ops.  The lex/yacc/C combination is fairly standard for simple compilers, the make/sh combination is useful for building, and the awk/sed line was the only way I could get the whole thing under 500 bytes. (It's at 498 bytes currently.)

### Code

```
define L
%%
[][+-<>.,] return *yytext;
. ;
%%
endef
define Y
%{
#include <stdio.h>
%}
%left '+' '-' '.' ',' '>' '<' '[' ']'
%%
q: q q {}
+ p[i]++
- p[i]--
> i++
< i--
, p[i]=getchar()
. putchar(p[i])
[ while(p[i]){
] }
%%
yywrap(){}yyerror(){}main(){puts("import std.stdio;int p[30000];int i;void main(){");yyparse();puts("}");}
endef
export L
export Y
a:
    @echo "$$L">y;lex y;echo "$$Y"|awk '/^[+-^]/{printf("q: X%sX {puts(\"%s;\");}\n",$$1,$$2)} /^[^+-^]/'|sed "y/X/'/">y;yacc y;cc *.c;./a.out;:
```

### Example of use

```
$ cat helloworld.bf
++++++++++[>+++++++>++++++++++>+++>+<<<<-]>++.>+.+++++++..+++.>++.<<+++++++++++++++.>.+++.------.--------.>+.>.
$ make < helloworld.bf > tmp.d
y: warning: 8 shift/reduce conflicts [-Wconflicts-sr]
$ dmd tmp.d && ./tmp
Hello World!
```

Comment: Wow haha! I'd count the input language if I were you haha! Processing it is really neat, creative solution to sneak an extra language in

Comment: Well, I think this answer is easily the best answer, but my question was put on hold and activity dropped, and since it's a "popularity contest" I have to chose the answer with the most votes, even though I think if it wasn't put [on hold] this would have easily been the first place answer. Sorry /:

Comment: make, awk and sed can all be easily executed by sh, regex can be easily parsed by sed. So, -1.

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ I agree with you on the regex, but the OP explicitly stated that regex should be counted, so I did.  I'm not sure I understand what you mean about make, awk, and sed being easily executed by sh.  I *do* call sed and awk from sh, although it's make that calls sh, not the other way around.  That said, sh was mainly needed for the I/O redirection and echo command. awk was needed for the input tokenization and regex, and sed was needed for the transliteration.  There were other ways to do all that, but not easily under 500 characters. (Besides, the *point* was to use many languages)

Comment: @Ray But you listed "sed" and "regex" separately, so I count them as one. Yet, you can say "make, dash, coreutils, yacc, lex".

Comment: Realized I could just remove my vote from the other answer thus making it a tie and I can select this as tie breaker since it's clearly the best answer. Loophole!

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw wow ok....

Answer (score 9):

## HTML, CSS, PHP, JavaScript, CoffeeScript, RegEx, sed, bash; 8 languages

Displays colors of the rainbow.

*(Only 396 bytes)* will try to add more languages

HTML + CSS is turning complete and counts as a valid language on PPCG. I've been [told](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24575556#24575556) CoffeeScript is different enough as JavaScript to be counted as a separate language. And RegEx has been specifically allowed also.

PHP allows for addition of many languages especially with `exec` and `shell_exec` functions.

Golfed to fit inside byte limit (ES6)

```html
<html><style><?php foreach(explode(" ",exec('sed "s/;/ /g"<<<"red;orange;yellow;green;blue;violet"')) as $color){echo "#{$color} { color: $color }\n"}?></style><script>b="red orange yellow green blue violet".split(/ /).map(c=>`<p id="${c}">${c}</p>`)</script><script type="text/coffeescript">document.documentElement.innerHTML+=b.join "\n"</script><script src="http://v.ht/u31R"></script></html>
```

Uses:

- PHP to generate CSS
- PHP, uses exec to run bash
- sed to split color items for bash
- CSS to specify text colors
- JavaScript to generate elements
- RegEx to split color items for JS
- CoffeScript to print elements
- HTML as a wrapper / output

---

Faster & Ungolfed (All modern browsers)

```html
<html>
<style>
  /* CSS */
  <?php// Loop through all colors
  foreach(explode(" ",
  exec('sed "s/;/ /g"<<<"red;orange;yellow;green;blue;violet"')) as $color) {
    // Print it out, add it to the CSS
    echo"#{$color} { color: $color }\n"}
 ?>
</style>
  
<script>
  // Create an element for each color, store as variable
  window.colors = "red orange yellow green blue violet".split(/ /).map(function(color) {
    return "<p id=\"" + color + "\">" + color + "</p>"
  });
</script>
  
<script type="text/coffeescript">
  document.documentElement.innerHTML += window.colors.join "\n"
</script>
  
<!-- CoffeScript Link -->
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/master/extras/coffee-script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Very nice seamless combination of the languages at hand

Comment: I sense a serious lack of XSLT. And the XPath that comes with it.

Comment: @Édouard I've tried to implement that but it's difficult implementing that in under 100 bytes. JavaScript doesn't have very consise XSLT but I'm working on it

Comment: What do you mean “JS doesn’t have concise XSLT”? Are you trying to use JS to apply your transformation?